# Ion-list not refreshing afer model change

Tags: angularjs, typescript, ionic3

I am having a problem with the ion-list, I can list all the items when the app loads for the first time, but when I make any changes to it, adding or removing data, the list isn't updating for the user.

I am using Pouch db to add and remove data for persistence in the app, all the functions are working correctly, it can be confirmed through console.log in the contents or using the fauxton PouchDb extension for chrome.

Resuming, the data is changing, but the view is not reflecting it.

the view code is this notas.html

```html
<ion-content>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let n of notas">
      <ion-item>
        <h2>{{n.descricao}}</h2>
        <p>URL: {{n.endereco}}</p>
        <p>Data de expiração: {{n.vencimento}}</p>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item-options side="right">
        <button ion-button (click)="editar(n)">
          <ion-icon name="paper"></ion-icon>
          Editar
        </button>
        <button ion-button color="danger" (click)="excluir(n)">
          <ion-icon name="trash"></ion-icon>
          Excluir
        </button>
      </ion-item-options>
    </ion-item-sliding>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

And the controler code is this notas.ts

```
...
@Component({
  selector: 'page-notas',
  templateUrl: 'notas.html'
})
export class NotasPage {
  notas: any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public alertCtrl: AlertController, public pouchDBService: PouchdbProvider) {
    //PARA USO DO EXTENSION DO CHROME *POUCHDB Fauxton
    (<any>window).PouchDB = PouchDB;
    this.notas = [];
  }

  ionViewDidLoad(){
    this.refresh();
  }

  refresh(){
    //console.log(this.notas);
    this.notas = [];
    this.pouchDBService.getData().then((data) => {
      this.notas = data;
      console.log(this.notas);
    });
    // console.log(this.notas);
  }

  excluir(nota){
    let prompt = this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: 'Excluir',
      message: 'Deseja realmente excluir o registro?',
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'Cancelar'
        },
        {
          text: 'Excluir',
          handler: data => {
            this.pouchDBService.delete(nota);
            this.notas.pop(nota);
            this.refresh();
          }
        }
      ]
    });

    prompt.present();
  }
}
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 100% sure on this but usually if the view is not updating, it has to do with the code not running on zone, so:

```
import { NgZone } from '@angular/core';
...
zone: any = new NgZone({ enableLongStackTrace: false });
```

And then change your refresh method to:

```
refresh(){
    //console.log(this.notas);
    this.notas = [];
    this.pouchDBService.getData().then((data) => {
      this.zone.run(() => {
        this.notas = data;
        console.log(this.notas);
      });
    });
    // console.log(this.notas);
  }
```

I believe that should work.